# Add links & Image for dynamic divs blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

currently working on dynamic blocks. I have created the code for dynamic div-block but when I tried to add dynamic Image and link for the dynamic blocks it was not working.

Output as below

[image]

Here is the code for the dyanmic div blocks

```
var data = ["Extension", "something else", "more","some data1", "something else1", "more1"];
$.each(data, function(i, v){
    $("#divId").append('<div class="single" id="my_test_' + (i+1) + '">'
                       +'<div class="any_name"> '+ v +' </div></div>');
});
```

Here is the explanation what I need.

When I tried to add Image for the div for example 
   image1.png
and I need to add link for the whole-div block.

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/5j2xgx81/)

Comment: Could you expand on `not working`?

Comment: How will be your logic to show dynamic images and links? /image1.jpg, /image2.jpg? The same for links?

Comment: hI@lago Melanias thanks for the reply I need to show as image1.png and I need to add link to the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an array with objects. Each object will have text, image and link properties. You will dynamically create all of the elements and append them. The anchor element (the link will go as wrapper to a single div in order all of the div content to be clickable). And inside the div you can append the image and the text.

Of course I didn't style them for you so you'll have to do that by yourself. You just need to change the data (put some correct image path and correct links with text) and the classes and do some css styling.

**Here is my working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5j2xgx81/2/**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divId"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var data = [
    {
        text: 'some data',
        link: 'http://www.google.com/',
        imagePath: 'some/path/img.jpg'
    },
    {
        text: 'something else',
        link: 'http://www.facebook.com/',
        imagePath: 'some/path/img2.jpg'
    }
];

$.each(data, function(key, value){
    var newDiv = $('<div/>')
                    .addClass('single')
                    .attr('id', 'my_test_' + (key + 1));

    var textInsideDiv = $('<span/>')
                            .addClass('blabla')
                            .text(value.text);

    var imageInsideDiv = $('<img/>')
                    .addClass('someclass')
                    .attr('src', value.imagePath);

    var linkWrapper = $('<a/>')
                 .addClass('someotherclass')
                 .attr('href', value.link);

    newDiv
        .append(imageInsideDiv)
        .append(textInsideDiv);
    linkWrapper.append(newDiv);

    $('#divId').append(linkWrapper);
});
```

Good luck :)